# MATLAB 7.6 Compile/Run Issue on Linux

Tags: matlab, compiler-construction

I have created a program (GUI) on MATLAB 7.6 (2010a) and compiled it using depoytool. however, when I try to run the program, it complains about a missig library file (libmwmclmcrrt.so.7.6). I have installed MCR, and I am trying to point to it by typing the filename followed by the path to the MCR, but nothing is working.

Suggestions?

Comment: How do you start the compiled program? show the command.

Comment: _filename_ (no extension) _MCR_directory_. Also tried setting an environment variable, _MCR_, to _MCR_directory_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On linux, MATLAB creates the startup script called `run_progname.sh`. You should run this script, and **not** your compiled program directly. Assuming you are in the directory where the program `progname` is compiled, execute

```
./run_progname.sh <deployedMCRroot> args
```

Comment: However, I noted today that this .sh file is located in the src directory, not in the distrib directory. Also, it looks for a parameter to the MCR location - I just made a .sh file (based on the generated one) with the MCR location hard-coded, since everyone will be accessing it over the network.